Goibibo / MakeMyTrip APi Integartion
I need to integrate MMT / Goibibo with my mobile App.
I have already registered on https://goibibo.3scale.net/ but APi documentation is not visible.
Can someone help and explain how to proceed?
I also sent a mail through portal but no response was received.

Speak to the supplier and get them to provide the required API specs and documentation.  How else are you expecting this to work?
